# arrange cutom Arraylist according to time column

Tags: android

I Have one Custom arraylist which contains multiple parameters along with time.

I want to sort that list according to time Parameter in asending and desending format

I searched alot 
Here are some links
[Sort objects in ArrayList by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date/37291086)

[Sort ArrayList with times in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671959/sort-arraylist-with-times-in-java)

and many more 
but none worked

Here is my code

**function calling on Click**

```
 private void callTimeSorting(ArrayList<ObjectClass>solutions){
    try{
        ArrayList<ObjectClass> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (tempList.size() > 0){tempList.clear();}
        tempList.addAll(solutions);
        if (mTimeTag == 1) {
            if (!mAsendingTime) {
                Collections.sort(tempList, AsendingTimeComparator);
                mAsendingTime = true;
                mAdapter.notify();
            } else {
                Collections.sort(tempList, DesendingTimeComparator);
                mAsendingTime = false;
            }

        }
 }
```

**OnClick method**

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id) {
       case R.id.tvTimings :
            mTimeTag =  1 ;
            callTimeSorting(mSolutions) ;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;


 }}
```

**AsendingComparator**

```
  private static Comparator<ObjectClass> AsendingTimeComparator = new Comparator<ObjectClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ObjectClass solution1, ObjectClass solution2) {
        String time1 = solution1.getDepartureDateTime();
        String time2 = solution2.getDepartureDateTime();
        return time1.compareTo(time2);//asending
    }
};

private static Comparator<ObjectClass> DesendingTimeComparator = new Comparator<ObjectClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ObjectClass solution1, ObjectClass solution2) {
        String time1 = solution1.getDepartureDateTime();
        String time2 = solution2.getDepartureDateTime();
        return time2.compareTo(time1);//descending

    }



};
```

I dont know why my sorted list is not attaching to recyclerView??

Comment: in set adapter which list you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the original list used in Adapter, not the temp one

```
 private void callTimeSorting(ArrayList<ObjectClass>solutions){
        try{
            ArrayList<ObjectClass> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList.addAll(solutions);
            solutions.clear();
            if (mTimeTag == 1) {
                if (!mAsendingTime) {
                    Collections.sort(tempList, AsendingTimeComparator);
                    mAsendingTime = true;
                } else {
                    Collections.sort(tempList, DesendingTimeComparator);
                    mAsendingTime = false;
                }
              solutions.addAll(tempList);
              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list is not getting sorted because you are sorting the tempList:

```
Collections.sort(tempList, AsendingTimeComparator);
```

And not the actual list your adapter is using i.e solutions.

You should not use templist and directly sort solutions.

```
private void callTimeSorting(ArrayList<ObjectClass>solutions){
    try{
        if (mTimeTag == 1) {
            if (!mAsendingTime) {
                Collections.sort(solutions, AsendingTimeComparator);
                mAsendingTime = true;
                mAdapter.notify();
            } else {
                Collections.sort(solutions, DesendingTimeComparator);
                mAsendingTime = false;
            }

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the reference of the mList** ... through out your code dont initialize it again.. use `clear()` instead of `new Arraylist<>` and dont assign any other reference to the list like `list = new_List;`

**The mAdapter would lose reference of the list... and wont work accordingly.. (notifyDataSetChanged() wont work.**